# Average and conversion order of operation

Tags: math, floating-point

I have a data that I need to analyse.
The data consists of a series of numbers (floating point) represent duration in milliseconds.

From the duration I need to calculate frequency of those events (occurrence in seconds). So I simply calculate it like

```
occurrence per second = (1000/ time in milliseconds)
```

Now I need to find the average occurrence of that event in seconds.

But I am not sure which would be accurate order of operation.

Should I average the duration first and then calculate the average occurrence by

```
average occurrence = (1000/average time)
```

or I should calculate the frequency for each duration and average the result?

Both case result varies a bit. So I am not sure which pne would be correct approach.

### Example:

Say we are measure frame rate of a device,

Each frame take x milliseconds to draw.
From that we can say

```
frame per second = (1000/x)
```

Now if my data has 1000 duration,

Either I can average them and get a average duration of a frame and get a `frame per second = (1000/average duration)`

or

we calculate 1000 frame per seconds first,

```
frame per seconds = (1000/duration)
```

and average those 100 fps value?

which one is correct?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please post your current code, because I'm unsure what you mean by `count = ( 1000/ time in miliseconds )` - because a `count` is not a frequency value...

Comment: Please clarify what-it-is you mean by "average count in second" - because that sounds exactly like the average-frequency (in Hz), which it sounds like you're already computing (" frequency of those events over a second").

Answer (score 0):

You should choose the first method: Calculate the average duration of each frame and then let avg_fps = 1000 / avg_duration_in_milliseconds, or, probably easier: avg_fps = number_of_frames / total_duration_in_seconds. This gives the same thing.

**Example:**

Say you have 3 frames in one second of durations 200ms, 300ms and 500ms. Since you have 3 frames in 1 second, ***the avg_fps is 3.***

The average duration is 333.33ms which gives the right result (1000/333.33 = 3). But if you calculate the individual fps of each frame you get (1000/200 = 5), (1000/300 = 3.33) and (1000/500 = 2). *The average of 5, 3.33 and 2 is **3.44*** - the highest values will skew the result in the wrong direction. So choose the first method instead.